Помогите, где я допустил ошибку? sep and input
Помогите ответить на два теста сразу:
input (,) test 1 January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December
input (==) test 2 January==February==March==April==May==June==July==August==September==October==November==December

так правильно только один
a =input()
print('January', 'February','March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December',sep=',')
'=='


не надо плодить одинаковые вопросы. свой вопрос вы можете править.

Вопрос задан конечно плохо, ведь ничего не понятно, но как я понял, тебе надо ввести список месяцев, разделенных запятыми, и затем вывести их с помощью разделителя , и ==.
Вот код:
months = input("Введите список месяцев, разделяя их запятыми: ")
print(*months.split(','), sep=',')
print(*months.split(','), sep='==')

